# Div does not show on change function but in ajax success it does

Tags: javascript, ajax

It's a very simple thing that I want to do, on change function I want **loading** div be visible, & through ajax request I'm filling up the content.
Now the thing is that **loading** div is not working in change function however it's working in ajax success function, I do not know where I'm making my mistake. Please have a look at my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#sub').change(function(){
    $('.autoload').empty();
    $('.loading').show(); // Here it doesn't work
    var val=$(this).val();
    $(this).value= val;
    if(val=='One'){
        var sub_cat=11;
    }
    else if(val=='Two'){
        var sub_cat=12;
    }
    else{
        var sub_cat=13;
    }
    var cat_id= <?php echo $cat_id; ?>;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_showsubdiv.php",
        data: {cat_id:cat_id,sub_cat:sub_cat},
        success: function(option){
            $('.loading').show(); // Here it's working
            $('.autoload').replaceWith(option);
            flag=false;
        }
    });
    $('.loading').hide();
});
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='autoload'></div>
<div class='loading'>
    <img src='acz.gif'>
</div>
```

Everything is working fine, data is coming fine, replacing perfectly, only thing is it takes time to show that loading div because it lies in success function, so only after ajax request is completed, div shows.
Can anyone tell why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `$('loading').hide();` at the bottom of the change function is executing and hiding the element almost immediately after calling `$('loading').show();`. Since AJAX is *asynchronous* the browser does not wait for `$.ajax()` calls to finish before continuing execution. Try removing this statement.